# IntelliJ Context Root Folders Shortcuts

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

In IntelliJ, I have context definitions for various directories.  For instance, my Java source directory looks like this:

[image]

However, I would like it to look like context folders in Eclipse, like this:

[image]

Is this possible in IntelliJ?